# Google App Engine: Caching a 30 mb object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to have an application cache.

Imagine I have a data-file that is in the format of "phrase\t".  So for example I have "baseball\t0.004".  Lets say I have millions of entries in this file and it's ~20-30mb.  The web-application would basically take any arbitrary paragraph of text and classify it by summing the values of the key-lookups on the phrases.  Since I want this application to run really fast, I'd like to do hundreds of these key-lookups in <300 ms.  What is the best way to ensure that the python code doesn't have to read the data-file each time the URL is invoked?  Is the best strategy for each phrase to be a key lookup in memcache?  I'm concerned that memcache may not actually be fast enough.  Ideally, I'd like to have a cache that loads with the application in App Engine.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Cache the contents of the file in a global variable, which I imagine would be a dictionary mapping phrase to score.  The global variable will survive for the lifetime of the instance, i.e. potentially across many requests.

Comment: While true that caching that way would be the best method, maybe using a global variable could be detrimental to the app. If the app spins more than one instance at once, then he would end up with two different global variables. A mix of global variables and memcache at once maybe? using memcache to share the variable... although for 30 mb, you might be better off using "dedicated memcache"